# Convert an apk file to zip file

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

At first, I have choose an apk named as bdteam. I tried utmost to find the source code. But i can not convert apk file to zip file. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: .apk files are .zip files. Just open them with your archiver or rename them to .zip or .jar if it doesn't work with the .apk file ending.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> APK files are a type of archive file, specifically in zip format packages based on the JAR file format, with .apk as the filename extension. The MIME type associated with APK files is application/vnd.android.package-archive.

So .APK **are** .ZIP files, you don't need any kind of converter, just use WinRAR it will handle them perfectly.

Here's what you want to do:

1. Right click on the APK file and choose `Open with`
2. Select `Choose another app`
3. Select WinRAR
4. Tick `Always use this app to open .APK files`

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy. Just rename the file to my file.zip and extract by any application.

Answer (score 0):

Just change APK to .zip.
Then change the certain type of file at the bottom to "All Files
then extract
very easy